# error: command failed: 'cargo': Bad CPU type in executable (os error 86)

Tags: anchor, solana-cli

I am trying to setup solana and anchor in macbook pro m1 but i am getting this error

```
anchor build
BPF SDK: /Users/pratik/.local/share/solana/install/releases/stable- 
18fe44c1a24e7ca5071f6f2159e4cb67ffa8307d/solana-release/bin/sdk/bpf
cargo-build-bpf child: rustup toolchain list -v
cargo-build-bpf child: cargo +bpf build --target bpfel-unknown-unknown --release
error: command failed: 'cargo': Bad CPU type in executable (os error 86)
```

Comment: Are you running this in a Rosetta terminal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Today I've encountered the same issue as you. The solution was quite simple: install Rosetta2 using

```
softwareupdate --install-rosetta
```

`Mac OS Ventura 13.1`, `cargo 1.66.1`, `solana-cli 1.15.0`, `anchor-cli 0.26.0`.

Comment: This works on solidity compiler `solc` as well!